# Solving "Error in if (obs <= ei) 2 * pv else 2 * (1 - pv) : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" for ape package Moran's I function in R

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, spatial

developers!

I have encountered an error message

> Error in if (obs <= ei) 2 * pv else 2 * (1 - pv) : missing value where
> TRUE/FALSE needed

stopping me to get the value from Moran's I function from ape package. Here is what I did:

```
library(ape)

nrstp <- data.frame(
     X = c(300226.9, 300224.6, 300226.4, 300226.1, 300224.0, 300226.4, 300225.7, 300226.4, 300226.1, 300226.4, 300226.3, 300226.3, 300227.1),
     Y = c(5057949, 5057952, 5057950, 5057950, 5057956, 5057950, 5057950, 5057950, 5057950, 5057950, 5057950, 5057950, 5057949),
     V3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

nrstp = data.frame(nrstp)
dist = as.matrix(dist(cbind(nrstp$X, nrstp$Y)))
invdist = 1/dist
invdist[is.infinite(invdist)] <- 0
moranI = Moran.I(nrstp$V3, invdist)
```

The intention of this code is to calculate Moran's I from a series of point to check spatial autocorrelation. So far, this seems to be the only function working for Moran's I in R. After a few testing (I have thousands groups of points), this error seems only happen to the input vector having only one value (I tried other numbers than 0, it still raise this error).

Could someone help me improve this code? Or are their better suggestion to calculate Moran's I or test spatial autocorrelation from linestring (those point groups are origin point of one linestring and the closest points from other linestring within 10 meter buffer of such origin point)?

Thank you ahead for any help!

Comment: What is your `V3` variable?

Answer (score 2):

The control flow choice `if(condition) do something` requires that the value of `condition` is not `NA`.

In your case, `obs <= ei` results in `NA`. That's why the  the error message `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed` is generated.

To understand how `obs <= ei` results in `NA`, you can check the details inside `Moran.I` function:

```
Moran.I
function (x, weight, scaled = FALSE, na.rm = FALSE, alternative = "two.sided") 
{
    if (dim(weight)[1] != dim(weight)[2]) 
        stop("'weight' must be a square matrix")
    n <- length(x)
    if (dim(weight)[1] != n) 
        stop("'weight' must have as many rows as observations in 'x'")
    ei <- -1/(n - 1)
    nas <- is.na(x)
    if (any(nas)) {
        if (na.rm) {
            x <- x[!nas]
            n <- length(x)
            weight <- weight[!nas, !nas]
        }
        else {
            warning("'x' has missing values: maybe you wanted to set na.rm = TRUE?")
            return(list(observed = NA, expected = ei, sd = NA, 
                p.value = NA))
        }
    }
    ROWSUM <- rowSums(weight)
    ROWSUM[ROWSUM == 0] <- 1
    weight <- weight/ROWSUM
    s <- sum(weight)
    m <- mean(x)
    y <- x - m
    cv <- sum(weight * y %o% y)
    v <- sum(y^2)
    obs <- (n/s) * (cv/v)
    if (scaled) {
        i.max <- (n/s) * (sd(rowSums(weight) * y)/sqrt(v/(n - 
            1)))
        obs <- obs/i.max
    }
    S1 <- 0.5 * sum((weight + t(weight))^2)
    S2 <- sum((apply(weight, 1, sum) + apply(weight, 2, sum))^2)
    s.sq <- s^2
    k <- (sum(y^4)/n)/(v/n)^2
    sdi <- sqrt((n * ((n^2 - 3 * n + 3) * S1 - n * S2 + 3 * s.sq) - 
        k * (n * (n - 1) * S1 - 2 * n * S2 + 6 * s.sq))/((n - 
        1) * (n - 2) * (n - 3) * s.sq) - 1/((n - 1)^2))
    alternative <- match.arg(alternative, c("two.sided", 
        "less", "greater"))
    pv <- pnorm(obs, mean = ei, sd = sdi)
    if (alternative == "two.sided") 
        pv <- if (obs <= ei) 
            2 * pv
        else 2 * (1 - pv)
    if (alternative == "greater") 
        pv <- 1 - pv
    list(observed = obs, expected = ei, sd = sdi, p.value = pv)
}
<bytecode: 0x000001cd5e0715d0>
<environment: namespace:ape>
```

By assigning `x = nrstp$V3` and `weight = invdist`, you will get `mean(x) = 0`. This results in `y=0`, `cv = 0`, `v=0`, and finally `obs = NaN`.  Consequently,

```
obs <= ei
[1] NA
```

To overcome the problem, you need to ensure that each of `obs` and `ei` is not `NA`. In your case, if `mean(x)` is not zero, `obs <= ei` will not be `NA`. However, because I know nothing about this particular topic, I'm not sure whether non-zero `mean(x)` is always the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `x` are all the same value. If you look in the code from Abdur Rohman the calculation of the function is

```
m <- mean(x)
    y <- x - m
    cv <- sum(weight * y %o% y)
    v <- sum(y^2)
    obs <- (n/s) * (cv/v)
```

if all `x` are the same than the mean of `m <- mean(x)` is obviously the same value as all `x` and `y, v, obs` are 0.
For `obs` you divide `cv/v` which is `NaN`

So at least one value of `x` should be different