# In R, how can I identify the specific cells that contain INFINITE values in my inverse distance matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, geospatial, infinite

**The context:** I'm using the ape package to calculate Moran's I, cannibalizing the procedure identified [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/faq/how-can-i-calculate-morans-i-in-r/). I keep getting this error:

> Error in if (obs <= ei) 2 * pv else 2 * (1 - pv) :    missing value
> where TRUE/FALSE needed

Rooting around on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663994/solving-error-in-if-obs-ei-2-pv-else-2-1-pv-missing-value-where) and [the Internet](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/troubles-performing-Moran-I-test-td878799.html), I have found some suggestions that this error can result from having infinite values or NA values. When I run *sum(is.infinite(inv.coord.distances))* I still end up with four infinite values. Using *sum(is.na())*, *sum(is.nan())* and *sum.is(null())* returns zero of those potential problems. When I manually search my 93x93 matrix, I do not see any INF values, though this method is not fool-proof. Nonetheless, I keep getting this error and my sum(is.infinite()) operation keeps telling me there are four infinite values. This happens whether I use UTM or latitude and longitude.

**My question**: Is there a command that returns the cell location of all my infinite values in my matrix? I tried *which(inv.coord.distances != inf)*, but evidently *which()* will not find infinite values in a matrix.

Comment: `which(is.infinite(inv.coord.distances))`

Comment: This works! Thank you kindly.

Comment: If anyone else stumbles on this problem in the future: the off-diagonal INF values should be symmetrical around the diagonal, as they represent cases where the two points occupy the same coordinates. I set them equal to one, though you might also set them equal to the largest observed value in your inverse distance matrix. Another solution might be to combine points occupying an identical location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer:**
To identify the specific cell or cells that contain INFINITE values in an inverse distance matrix, I used...

> which(is.infinite(inv.coord.distances))

as suggeted by [dww].

To convert the cells returned to their rows and columns, divide the value by the number of columns in a row. The whole number is the row number. Next, multiply the proportion left over by the number of columns in a row. This identifies the column.

For instance, 1008 was one of my four cells containing the INF value. 1008/93 = 10.83871. This cell is located in row 10 and column 78 (since 0.83871* 93 =  78.00003).

The tidyverse solution provided by [OftenOverkilledSolutions] should alse reveal the offending cells:

> as_tibble(inv.coord.distances) %>%
> mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
> gather(Column,Value,-row) %>%
> filter(is.na(Value)) #Or some other condition here

Answer (score 0):

Seriously an overkill solution, but this can be super flexible and generalized to do many other things.

```
    library(tidyverse)

    as_tibble(inv.coord.distances) %>% 
       mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
       gather(Column,Value,-row) %>% 
       filter(is.na(Value)) #Or some other condition here
```

Comment: I haven't used the tidyverse package yet, but will definitely file this away. Thank you kindly.